# Convert Typescript to Javascript - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How would I write this Typescript code in Javascript?

```
function ImageMagnifier({
  src,
  width,
  height,
  magnifierHeight = 100,
  magnifieWidth = 100,
  zoomLevel = 1.5
}: {
  src: string;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  magnifierHeight?: number;
  magnifieWidth?: number;
  zoomLevel?: number;
}) {
const [[x, y], setXY] = useState([0, 0]);
  const [[imgWidth, imgHeight], setSize] = useState([0, 0]);
  const [showMagnifier, setShowMagnifier] = useState(false);
```

I found the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/image-magnifier-3jsqs?from-embed=&file=/src/App.tsx:77-498

but i am getting errors when i use it in a jsx file because its typescript.

the part in particular its having issues with is

```
src: string;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  magnifierHeight?: number;
  magnifieWidth?: number;
  zoomLevel?: number;
```

UPDATE:

I tried the code in the first answer and the error is gone and the magnifier seems to work except that I get broken images. see attached image [image: Broken images]

When i check my console i see that the src=[object Object] - see attached image
[image: console log]

my ImageMagnifier React component code:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";


function ImageMagnifier(
    src,
    width,
    height,
    magnifierHeight = 100,
    magnifieWidth = 100,
    zoomLevel = 1.5
  )
{
  const [[x, y], setXY] = useState([0, 0]);
  const [[imgWidth, imgHeight], setSize] = useState([0, 0]);
  const [showMagnifier, setShowMagnifier] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        height: height,
        width: width
      }}
    >
      <img
        src={src}
        style={{ height: height, width: width }}
        onMouseEnter={(e) => {
          // update image size and turn-on magnifier
          const elem = e.currentTarget;
          const { width, height } = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
          setSize([width, height]);
          setShowMagnifier(true);
        }}
        onMouseMove={(e) => {
          // update cursor position
          const elem = e.currentTarget;
          const { top, left } = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

          // calculate cursor position on the image
          const x = e.pageX - left - window.pageXOffset;
          const y = e.pageY - top - window.pageYOffset;
          setXY([x, y]);
        }}
        onMouseLeave={() => {
          // close magnifier
          setShowMagnifier(false);
        }}
        alt={"img"}
      />

      <div
        style={{
          display: showMagnifier ? "" : "none",
          position: "absolute",

          // prevent maginier blocks the mousemove event of img
          pointerEvents: "none",
          // set size of magnifier
          height: `${magnifierHeight}px`,
          width: `${magnifieWidth}px`,
          // move element center to cursor pos
          top: `${y - magnifierHeight / 2}px`,
          left: `${x - magnifieWidth / 2}px`,
          opacity: "1", // reduce opacity so you can verify position
          border: "1px solid lightgray",
          backgroundColor: "white",
          backgroundImage: `url('${src}')`,
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",

          //calculate zoomed image size
          backgroundSize: `${imgWidth * zoomLevel}px ${
            imgHeight * zoomLevel
          }px`,

          //calculete position of zoomed image.
          backgroundPositionX: `${-x * zoomLevel + magnifieWidth / 2}px`,
          backgroundPositionY: `${-y * zoomLevel + magnifierHeight / 2}px`
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ImageMagnifier;

// export default function App() {
//   return (
//     <div className="App">
//       <ImageMagnifier
//         width={"200px"}
//         src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/616HiOFb1VL._AC_UX679_.jpg"
//       />
//     </div>
//   );
// }
```

my code where I output the images

```
import useStore from "../../../store";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import ImageMagnifier from "../../image/ImageMagnifier";


const Thread = ({thread}) => {

    const threadColor = useStore(state => state.threadColor);
    const setThreadColor = useStore(state => state.setThreadColor);

    const threadFeature = useStore(state => state.threadFeature);
    const setThreadFeature = useStore(state => state.setThreadFeature);

    const change = (e)=> {
        setThreadColor(e.target.dataset.name);
        setThreadFeature(e.target.dataset.feature);
}

    return (
        <div>

            <ImageMagnifier
                    width={"400px"}
                    src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/616HiOFb1VL._AC_UX679_.jpg"
                    >
            </ImageMagnifier>
{/*     
       //  <Image  
             //   style={{
             //       borderRadius: '50px'
             //   }}
              
            //  onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
            //   onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
           //    onClick={change}
         //      data-name={thread?.name}
         //      data-feature={thread?.threadFields?.threadFeature}
         //      src={thread?.threadFields?.threadImage?.sourceUrl ?? //''}
 //              alt={ thread?.threadFields?.threadImage?.altText ?? //'' }
 //              title={ thread?.threadFields?.threadImage?.title ?? //''}
  //            width="100"
   //            height="50"

           /> */}
       
             </div>
        
    );
};

export default Thread;
```

the code where i get the grapghql data:

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
import Thread from './Thread';


const THREADS_QUERY = gql ` query {
    threads {
        nodes {
          name
          threadFields {
            threadColor
            threadFeature
            threadImage {
              sourceUrl
              title
              altText
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }`;

  function DisplayThreads() {
   
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(THREADS_QUERY);

    console.log('data:',data);
    if (isEmpty ( data )){
      return null;
    }

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  
   return (
     <>


         {data.threads.nodes.map((thread, i) => (
              <Thread key={i} thread={thread}/>
            
           ))} 

   </>
    )
  }


const ThreadColors = () => {

    return (
       <>
              <h3>Select Symbol Colour</h3>
              <div className="d-flex">
                 <DisplayThreads/>
              </div>

       </>
    );
};

export default ThreadColors;
```

at first I thought ImageMagnifier had an issue with my image src given that it is generated from a graphql fetch however when i use the image from the original code (which is a live working image - https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/616HiOFb1VL._AC_UX679_.jpg ) I still get the broken images result ( src=[object Object])

would really appreciate help to figure this out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the whole

```
: {
  src: string;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  magnifierHeight?: number;
  magnifieWidth?: number;
  zoomLevel?: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this way.

```
function ImageMagnifier(
  src,
  width,
  height,
  magnifierHeight = 100,
  magnifieWidth = 100,
  zoomLevel = 1.5
)
```